# How to get exact point of intersection of a plot with axis?

Tags: plotting, intersection

I have a parametric plot y(t) vs. x(t). I want to know exactly at what value of x,  this y vs x curve crosses the x-axis? I tried with "Get coordinates" of Drawing tools but this is not so accurate.
Can anyone please tell me how I can print the exact point of intersection between this curve and x-axis?

I want to find at what value of t, dbdt becomes zero.

Comment: How about `Solve[y[t]==0,t]`

Comment: I had tried with Solve too. But it was taking so much time (more than half an hour and still running) to print output! Actually these functions are not so simple. They both are like implicit functions f(x(y(z...)))). I don't care about the value of the independent variable t at which y becomes zero. I need the value of x only. If there is a faster way, please let me know.

Comment: Can you give what you actually have in code?

Comment: Have you tried `NSolve[]` instead?

Comment: `A = 1 + 2/Sqrt[x^2 + 1];
A0 = 1 + 2/Sqrt[x0^2 + 1];
B = 2* Re[
   NIntegrate[
    1/(\[x]^2*A^2*Sqrt[1/(x0^2*A0^4) - 1/(x^2*A^4)]), {x, 
     x0, \[Infinity]}]]
t = ArcSin[x0*A0^2]
(*dadr and dtdr are derivatives of B and t*)
dbdt = (Cos[b]/
   Cos[t] )^2*(1 - 
    1/2*(1 + ( Cos[t] /Cos[B - t])^2 (dBdr/ dtdr - 1)))
(*where b is a function like ArcTan[some function of B,t]*)`
Now I want to know at what value of t dbdt becomes zero.

Comment: i can't write full code because it's part of my new project.

Comment: @BenKalziqi Yes, I tried with NSolve too. Same problem. Too much time taking. No output even after running for nearly half an hour.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, and provide a functioning code, this code won't run.

Comment: Provide the values of `x0` etc. What is the parametric variable?

Comment: @Feyre I just added the code in my question. Please see if it helps in understanding my question.

Comment: x0 is the independent variable. I can choose any value between 0 to \infty.

Comment: And the other parameters? `b` etc?

Comment: b is a function. Please see the last line of the code.

Comment: `FindRoot[]` is the way to find roots numerically, especially of equations that are difficult (e.g. non-analytic, use a numerical procedure such as `NIntegrate`, etc.).  You should post code that adequately reproduces the computational issue you're having, but it doesn't have to be your private/confidential code.

Comment: The code as it stands is not functional - it does return only errors. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I just now posted a code which works fine.

Comment: It still doesn't work. You're trying `NIntegrate[]` to a non-numerical value `x0`.

Comment: Please check the code. The range of x0 is  {x0, 0.001, 50}. Obviously it  is not non-numerical value. I don't understand why mathematica shows such errors and still plots A(x0). If x0 were indeed non-numerical, why is mathematica plotting A(x0)?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `MeshFunctions`, though I don't know the precision :

```
gr00 = ParametricPlot[{t, t^2 - 1}, {t, 0, 2}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshFunctions ->  {#2 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.05]]]
```

[image]

```
Cases[Normal[gr00], Point[___], {1, Infinity}]
```

> {Point[{0.999811, 0.}]}

Comment: I got blank {{}} as output!

Comment: This probably won't work if the curve is tangent to the axis.  Not sure what to recommend for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
x[u_] := Sin[u]
y[u_] := Sin[2 u]
ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Solve for `u` an equation $y(u)=0$:

```
sol = u /. Solve[y[u] == 0, u]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[[Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg), C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg) [Element] Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1/2 ([Pi] + 2 [Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg)), 
>     C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg) [Element] Integers]}

Evaluate `x[u]` taking `sol` as input and taking into account the conditions from the `ConditionalExpression`s:

```
Table[Simplify[x[sol[[i]]], Assumptions -> sol[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, Length@sol}]
```

> {0, (-1)^C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg)}

One probably has to check what values can `C[1]` take (in this case `Integers`), so maybe instead

```
Simplify[x[sol], Assumptions -> sol]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[Sin[[Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg)], C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg) [Element] Integers], 
>    ConditionalExpression[Cos[[Pi] C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg)], C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwxCt.jpg) [Element] Integers]}

which on the other hand returns a slightly less clear solution.

---

**EDIT:** I developed a different method, suitable for this problem also, while answering [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127163/22013).

Let's take the plot in the form

```
x[u_] := Sin[u]
y[u_] := Sin[2 u]
curve = Show[
  ParametricPlot[{x[u], y[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None], 
  Plot[0, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

and extract the pixel positions of intersection with

```
px = PixelValuePositions[#, White] & @
  MorphologicalBranchPoints @ Thinning @ Binarize @ ColorNegate @ curve
```

> {{180, 182}, {2, 180}, {180, 180}, {359, 180}, {180, 179}}

We need to connect them to the actual coordinates on the plot:

```
pl = PlotRange@curve
```

> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 0.999999}}

```
id = ImageDimensions@curve
```

> {360, 360}

The relation between `pl` and `id` is linear, $y=ax+b$ and $y=cx+d$ in the horizontal and vertical directions, respecively:

```
{a, b} = {a, b} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[1, 1]] == b, pl[[1, 2]] == a id[[1]] + b}, {a, b}]
{c, d} = {c, d} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[2, 1]] == d, pl[[2, 2]] == c id[[2]] + d}, {c, d}]
```

> {0.00555555, -1.}
>
> {0.00555555, -1.}

The pixel positions transformed to plot coordinates:

```
ic = {a #1 + b, c #2 + d} & @@@ px
```

> {{9.49664*10^-9, 
>     0.011111}, {-0.988889, -1.50139*10^-7}, {9.49664*10^-9, \
>   -1.50139*10^-7}, {0.994444, -1.50139*10^-7}, {9.49664*10^-9, \
>   -0.0055557}}

look like this:

[image]

We can get rid of the ambiguity (5 points for 3 intersections) with clustering:

```
clu = ClusterClassify[ic, Method -> "DBSCAN"]
```

> Number of clusters: 3

```
g = GatherBy[ic, clu]
icmean = Chop[#, 10^-6] &@Reverse[Mean /@ g]
```

> {{0.994444, 0}, {-0.988889, 0}, {0, 0.0018517}}

```
Show[curve, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[#]}] &@icmean]
```

[image]

which looks very good; `icmean` are the positions of the three intersections.